# Unity 3d 2017.2.1 camera feed looks zoomed in iPad

Tags: ipad, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraFeed : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
public Renderer rend;

void Start () {


    WebCamDevice[] devices = WebCamTexture.devices;

    // for debugging purposes, prints available devices to the console
    for(int i = 0; i < devices.Length; i++)
    {
        print("Webcam available: " + devices[i].name);
    }

    Renderer rend = this.GetComponentInChildren<Renderer>();

    // assuming the first available WebCam is desired
    WebCamTexture tex = new WebCamTexture(devices[0].name);
    rend.material.mainTexture = tex;
    //rend.material.SetTextureScale("tex", new Vector2(1.2f, 1.2f));
    tex.Play();

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
}
```

I use the above code to render camera feed on a plane. The code works fine but I see zoomed feed(around 1.2x) when deployed to iPad. How can I get the normal feed. Or How do I zoom out the camera feed

Answer (score 0):

According to https://answers.unity.com/questions/1421387/webcamtexture-zoomed-in-on-ipad-pro.html if you insert this code it should scale properly:

```
rend.material.SetTextureScale("_Texture", new Vector2(1f, 1f))
```

Furthermore, it seems that you were trying something like this but your vector was off (by 0.2f) though you have commented out that line as well.  You could reduce the scale even more though that could make the image just smaller if the camera couldn't support that zoomout :).